Increment only the last number after leading 0s in a string
I am trying to write a method that takes a number and increases it by 1 if the format is correct. For an entry such as 001 the output should be 002 - this works. For 009 however, I have the issue that it doesn't add up to 010 but instead I get 0085.
This is my code:
int position = 1;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] numberCharArray = number.toCharArray();
       for(int i = numberCharArray.length-1; i>=0; i--){
                 if (i == numberCharArray.length-1 && Character.isDigit(numberCharArray[i])){
                       if(Character.getNumericValue(numberCharArray[i]) < 9){
                                sb.append(Character.getNumericValue(numberCharArray[i]) + position);
                            } else if(Character.getNumericValue(numberCharArray[i]) == 9){
                                if (Character.isDigit(numberCharArray[i - 2]) && i > 2) {
                                    sb.append(0);
                                } else{
                                    
                                    sb.append(numberCharArray[i] + position);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            sb.append(numberCharArray[i]);
                        }
                    }
number = sb.reverse().toString();

How do I get it to replace a 0 by a 1 to get 010?

Do not use the StringBuilder. Simply work on the char[] numberCharArray like you would. Calling number.toCharArray() creates a copy anyway, so no chance of messing with the original String number. And finally, create a new String(numberCharArray);.

I don't see why you'd look at individual characters. You should be looking at groups of digits and incrementing them

Second, easier solution: If you know how long the 'number' part of the String is, simply parse it, increment it, create a new String with appended 0s.

@JayC667 how would I change it in place for the case where it goes from 009 to 010?

Please repost and format your code and ensure it compiles.  You are missing various elements and have syntax errors. (e.g. where is filmNumberCharArray?)  It would help to show an example of a typical input and the expected output using valid formats and those that should be ignored.

It's edited now.

What if you had a string like "004 0009 00001"?  would you want all the numbers to be incremented to yield "005 0010 00002"?

Are you trying to create a string that represents an integer but is always the same length? ie 0001, 0002, ..., 0010, 0011, ..., 0100, 0101 ?

new DecimalFormat(str.replaceAll("\\d","0")).format(new BigInteger(str).add(BigInteger.ONE)) (assuming only digits in the String str)

Would you please answer my enquiry in the comments above?  Also, what if the number had no leading zeros?  E.g.  Test999 do we just increment to test1000 or test01000 or ignore it.  You omitted quite a few details which made it hard to provide an answer without guessing.

I would treat the numbers as matched groups, for example:
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class IncNums {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Pattern numGroup = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String input = args[0];
        Matcher m = numGroup.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            int start = m.start();
            int end = m.end();
            int groupLength = end - start;
            String incrementedFormat = "%0" + groupLength + "d";
            int incremented = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start, end)) + 1;
            String rep = incrementedFormat.formatted(incremented);
            m.appendReplacement(sb, rep);

        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}


Java has some tools for this. If you have a 0 padded string you can get an integer.
String str = "0001";
int i = Integer.parseInt(str);

Now i is one. Then increment and turn it back into a string.
String s = String.format("%04d", i+1);

That will give you a 0 padded string representation of the next number.
What if you don't know the padding length? You can construct the format string.
String format = "%0" + str.length() + "d";
String s = String.format(format, i+1);


You commented:

how would I change it in place for the case where it goes from 009 to 010?

Parse the text as an int, increment, and generate text formatted with leading zeros.
int x = Integer.parseInt( "009" ) ;
int y = x + 1 ;
String z = String.format( "%03d" , y );
System.out.println( z ) ;

Or, in one line:
String.format( "%03d" , Integer.parseInt( "009" ) + 1  ) 

See this code run at Ide.

010


Here is one way. For the following test cases it produces the subsequent output.
System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("text 122 text0123"));
System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("text 122 text00123text"));
System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("text 122 00123text"));
System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("text 122 text0123"));

System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("No digits here"));
System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("text 122 text9"));
System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("text 122 text99text"));
System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("text 122 999text"));


System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("text 122 0123"));
System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("text 122 000123"));
System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("text 122 9999"));

System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("00000020202"));
System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("99999999999"));
System.out.println(incrementLastNumber("89999999999"));

prints
text 122 text0124
text 122 text00124text
text 122 00124text
text 122 text0124
No digits here
text 122 text9
text 122 text99text
text 122 999text
text 122 0124
text 122 000124
text 122 9999
00000020203
99999999999
90000000000


the program simply iterates over the characters in reverse order, first finding the start of the first digit from the end.
Then, continuing from that point, if the digit is 9 it replaces it with 0 and continues to the next digit.
otherwise it increments that digit and returns the new string.
if the after incrementing the character is no longer a digit, then the field width was exceeded and the original string returned.

public static String incrementLastNumber(String str) {
    char[] c = str.toCharArray();

    // find first digit from end.
    int start = c.length;
    while (start > 0 && !Character.isDigit(c[--start]));

    for (int i = start; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (c[i] == '9') {
            c[i] = '0';
        } else {
            c[i]++;
            if (!Character.isDigit(c[i])) {
                // processed a non-digit so
                // return original string
                return str;
            }

            // simple increment
            // no need to process further digits
            return new String(c);
        }

    }
    return str; // no changes made
}

There are two conditions where no changes were made.

no digits were present in the string.
the last number could not be incremented without widening its field as it was filled with 9's

Since there was no guidance on this (and other potential edge cases), the decision was made to simply return the original string.

Yoy can use BigInteger to convert str -> num -> str
public static String inc(String str) {
    BigInteger num = new BigInteger(str).add(BigInteger.ONE);
    return String.format("%0" + str.length() + "d", num);
}

As alternative, you can do it using sting manipulation.
public static String inc(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    int inc = 1;

    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (inc == 0)
            buf.append(str.charAt(i));
        else {
            int d = str.charAt(i) - '0' + inc;
            buf.append(d % 10);
            inc = d / 10;
        }
    }

    return inc == 0 ? buf.reverse().toString() : str;
}


Everyone's giving you solutions that rely on parsing the number as an int and then formatting it after figuring out the format, but for a simple "increment this value", that isn't needed. Your initial code was actually close to something that would work; try this:
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static String incStr(String number) {
        boolean doneWork = false;
        boolean foundNumber = false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        char[] numberCharArray = number.toCharArray();
        for(int i = numberCharArray.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            char thisChar = numberCharArray[i];
            if (doneWork) {
                sb.append(thisChar);
                continue;
            }
            if (!Character.isDigit(thisChar)) {
                if (foundNumber) {
                    sb.append('1');
                    doneWork = true;
                }
                sb.append(thisChar);
            } else if (Character.getNumericValue(thisChar) < 9) {
                sb.append(Character.getNumericValue(thisChar) + 1);
                doneWork = true;
            } else {
                foundNumber = true;
                sb.append('0');
            }
        }
        return sb.reverse().toString();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (String n : Arrays.asList("010", "xyz-000999-def", "x69", "Agent-99")) {
            System.out.println(n + " becomes " + incStr(n));
        }
    }
}

That outputs:
010 becomes 011
xyz-000999-def becomes xyz-001000-def
x69 becomes x70
Agent-99 becomes Agent-100

Note that this code will only increment the last sequence of digits in an input string, so if you have aaa-012-bbb-99 you'll end up with aaa-012-bbb-100.

Here is my solution according to my comment:
package stackoverflow;

public class StringIncrement {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        test("Hello World007"); // -> Hello World008
        test("Hello World007test"); // -> Hello World008test
        test("Hello World009test"); // -> Hello World010test
        test("Hello World-Test"); // -> (no change) Hello World-Test
        test("Hello World899test"); // -> Hello World900test
        test("Hello World999test"); // -> ERROR for String [Hello World999test]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot increment the String [Hello World999test] any further!
        test("Hello123 World456"); // -> Hello123 World457
    }

    static private void test(final String pString) {
        try {
            System.out.println(pString + "\t-> " + incrementString(pString));
        } catch (final IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR for String [" + pString + "]: " + e);
        }
    }

    static public String incrementString(final String pString) throws IllegalStateException {
        if (pString == null || pString.trim().length() < 1) return pString;

        final char[] chars = pString.toCharArray();
        boolean stringChanged = false;
        boolean digitFound = false;
        boolean carryOne = true;

        for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0 && carryOne; --i) { // reverse-iterate until carryOne is false
            final char c = chars[i];
            if (c == '.' || c == ',') continue;
            // if (!Character.isDigit(c)) we do NOT use this, but only focus on ISO-LATIN-1 digits
            if (c < '0' || '9' < c) { // hit a non-digit char here, but still have carryOne
                if (digitFound) throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot increment the String [" + pString + "] any further!");
                continue;
            }

            digitFound = true;
            final int value = Character.getNumericValue(c) + 1; // here carryOne is always true
            if (value > 9) {
                chars[i] = '0'; // do not set carryOne = false yet!
            } else {
                chars[i] = (char) ('0' + value);
                carryOne = false;
            }
            stringChanged = true;
        }
        if (!stringChanged) return pString;
        return new String(chars);
    }

}

Advantages:

Does NOT rely on full parsing
Has no problems if there are no digits in the String
Probably the fastest solution
Number can be anywhere inside the String
Will only increase the last (rightmost) number encountered in the String and will NOT carry over from rightmost number to other numbers
Will NOT create a copy of the String, but return the String (reference) itself, when no changes were made.
Easily adjustable to further needs.

Advantage and Disadvantage:

Will NOT extend the 'places' (digit-count) of the numerical parts. I.e. if the String is limited to 5 digits, it will stay limited and the algorithm will throw an Exception if it needs to exceed those digits.

Disadvantages:

Will ONLY handle ISO-LATIN-1 digits; Will ignore Arabic-Indic, Extended Arabic-Indic, Devanagari or Fullwidth digits (see Character.isDigit(char) java doc).
Will ignore problems when encountering multiple separators like ,, or .. (but could easily be fixed)

